# cpp read txt file and get values in line (Title, message)

Tags: c++, text-files, fopen, fstream, readline

I am a python programer but need to do this in cpp.

I have a txt file example

```
Title="Title 1" Description="Description 1"
Title="Title 2" Description="Description 2"
Title="Title 3" Description="Description 3"
```

i want to read this txt file line by line in cpp and separate key value in each line and save in STL map.

output :
key1 : "Title 1" , Value = "Description 1"

key2 : "Title 2" , Value = "Description 2"

Python code

```
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
lines = file1.readlines()
data = dict()
for line in lines:
    temp = line.split('"') 
    data[temp[1]] = temp[3]

display(data)
```

I am able to open file in cpp but struggling with rest of the codes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   fstream file;
   file.open("myfile.txt",ios::in);

   if (file.is_open())
   {
      string str;
      while(getline(file, str))
      {
         cout << str << "\n";
         // need to write other rest of the logic here

      }
      file.close();
   }
}
```

So basically

1. i am able to read file line by line.
2. struggling with splitting the text.
3. STL map i can do , if i have the text in two string title and Desc.

feel free to suggest if there any better way to read file as well.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show your attempt so far.

Comment: Can we see what code you were able to write?  Can you describe what part of this task you are currently struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

After reading in the line as a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) using [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), you can use the function [`std::string:find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to find the position of the next `=` character. You can then verify that the next character is a `"` character that marks the start of the value's string, and then use `str::string::find` again to find the closing `"`. You can repeat this until you reach the end of the line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    //open file
    std::ifstream file( "myfile.txt" );
    if ( !file )
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file!\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string str;

    //read one line of the file per loop iteration
    while( getline( file, str ) )
    {
        std::string::size_type pos1 = 0, pos2;

        std::cout << "Parsing line: " << str << "\n";

        //repeat loop as long as end of next key string is found
        while ( (pos2=str.find('=',pos1)) != std::string::npos )
        {
            std::cout <<
                "Found key: " <<
                str.substr( pos1, pos2-pos1 ) <<
                '\n';

            //make "pos1" point to " character
            pos1 = pos2 + 1;

            //verify that "pos1" actually points to a " character
            if ( str[pos1] != '"' )
            {
                std::cout << "Unexpected character encountered!\n";
                continue;
            }

            //make "pos1" point to start of value string
            pos1++;

            //find end of value string
            pos2 = str.find( '"', pos1 );
            if ( pos2 == std::string::npos )
            {
                std::cout << "Parse error.\n";
                continue;
            }

            //print the value string
            std::cout <<
                "Found value: " <<
                str.substr( pos1, pos2-pos1 ) <<
                '\n';

            pos1 = pos2 + 1;

            //jump past any whitespace characters
            while ( std::isspace( static_cast<unsigned char>(str[pos1]) ) )
                pos1++;
        }
    }
}
```

For the input specfied in the question, this program has the following output:

```
Parsing line: Title="Title 1" Description="Description 1"
Found key: Title
Found value: Title 1
Found key: Description
Found value: Description 1
Parsing line: Title="Title 2" Description="Description 2"
Found key: Title
Found value: Title 2
Found key: Description
Found value: Description 2
Parsing line: Title="Title 3" Description="Description 3"
Found key: Title
Found value: Title 3
Found key: Description
Found value: Description 3
```

Since you stated in your question that your only problem is parsing the line contents, I will not address the rest of your task.